# Can I push data from Home Assistant to a webpage?

Tags: home-assistant

I've just started to set up a home assistant instance, and I'm thinking that I'd like a way to publish some of the data in a 'read-only' sort of sense to a cloud-hosted web page.

Obviously, I could just open a port to my LAN, or sign up for Home assistant cloud - but I already have WAN connected control of most of my devices (just not the data logging). It seems that pushing PNG images to a website or similar would be a bit more secure, and maybe already done somewhere already.

I'm having trouble searching since most information seems to be about collecting sensor data, or normal remote access to home assistant. Are there any existing packages that provide this sort of feature?

To clarify, I'd like to push the image below (or generate the same effect), without actually writing any code (being more at the hardware/u-arch end of the spectrum)...

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can publish data by using tcp/ip communication and forwarding the data to web-port by using a web server like NGINX.
Please visit https://www.nginx.com/ for more information.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a bit too high level an answer to be useful. What would I put in a HA config file to achieve this?

Comment: Check the web server installed on your iot device.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question Sean asked.